# How to get RFC822 Email ID data from certificate using java

Tags: java

I am reading certificate from my USB Token as

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, null) ;
Enumeration en = ks.aliases() ;
while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
    String aliasKey = (String)en.nextElement() ;
    Certificate c = ks.getCertificate(aliasKey) ;
    System.out.println("---> alias : " + aliasKey) ;
    if (ks.isKeyEntry(aliasKey)) {
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(aliasKey);
        System.out.println("---> chain length: " + chain.length);
        for (Certificate cert: chain) {
            System.out.println(cert);
    }
}
```

I want read  RFC822 Email ID Certificate Data using java.

Comment: Do you mean email address?   The only ID defined by the RFC 822 is the Mesage-ID, and you won't find one of those in a Certificate ...

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] value = certificate.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.17");
email = new String(value, "UTF-8");
```